# How to convert string to UTF-8 byte array in PHP for Java BufferedInputStream.read()?

Tags: java, php, sockets, character-encoding

I need to make Java socket client and PHP-cli socket server and need to send client a UTF-8 encoded byte array and make so that Java BufferedInputStream.read() function would accept it.

**[SERVER]**

```
$input = socket_read($client[$i]['sock'],1024,PHP_BINARY_READ);
if($input==null || $input===FALSE) {unset($client[$i]);}
socket_write($client[$i]['sock'], unpack('C*', utf8_encode($input)));
```

**[CLIENT]**

```
out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();

in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] b = new byte[]{};
str = new String(in.read(b), "UTF-8");
System.out.println("[SOCKET] Server: " + str);
```

So i need a PHP analogue of
`String.getBytes("UTF-8");`
Thanks for feedback!

Comment: @JoopEggen nothing changed with `unpack('C*', utf8_encode($str));`.

Comment: Simply without `unpack`. But never much used pack/unpack myself.

Answer (score 0):

Change your inputstream. That solved my issue. Try change the rule:

```
in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

To:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

On PHP side you can use `utf8_encode` to encode your String to UTF-8. E.g.

```
$message = utf8_encode($message);
if ( ($fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3) ) === FALSE)
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
else {
    print 'SUCCESS!<br />';
    fwrite($fp, $message);
```